# TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined when using two controllers

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create a pop up using modal class in bootstrap and I am getting the following error - 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined

```
    angular.module('storagewebApp').controller('controller',['$scope','$modal', function($scope,$modal) {

            $scope.threshold = [];
            $scope.open = function(){
            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            animation: true,
            templateUrl: 'views/view1.html',
            controller: 'controller2',
            resolve: {
            items: function(){
                return $scope.threshold;
            }
        }
        });
           modalInstance.result.then(function (changed_threshold){
            $scope.threshold = changed_threshold;
       });
   };

}]);
    angular.module('storagewebApp').controller('controller2',function($scope, $modalInstance, items) {
$scope.threshold = items;
$scope.selected = [];
$scope.ok = function(){
    $modalInstance.close();
};
$scope.cancel = function(){
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
}
```

});

I have seperate app.js in which all the services are included --

```
    angular.module('storagewebApp', [
    'ngMessages',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize','ui.select', 'ui.bootstrap'])
.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/view.html',
            controller: 'controller'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
});
```

Following is the error that I am getting :

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined
at Scope.$scope.open (http://unixdeva16.factset.com/~sokumar/www/stud/app/scripts/controllers/controller.js:804:29)
at fn (eval at <anonymous> (http://unixdeva16.factset.com/~sokumar/www/stud/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:13036:15), <anonymous>:2:203)
at callback (http://unixdeva16.factset.com/~sokumar/www/stud/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:23090:17)
at Scope.$eval (http://unixdeva16.factset.com/~sokumar/www/stud/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:15719:28)
at Scope.$apply (http://unixdeva16.factset.com/~sokumar/www/stud/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:15818:23)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (http://unixdeva16.factset.com/~sokumar/www/stud/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:23095:23)
at HTMLButtonElement.n.event.dispatch (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js:3:6404)
at HTMLButtonElement.r.handle (http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js:3:3179)(anonymous function) @ angular.js:12221
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you do not include the `modal` services in your app, try:

```
 angular.module('storagewebApp', ['ui.bootstrap'])...
```

I'm not sure if the module is "ui.bootstrap" add that to your application or the name of the module containing `modal`

In this "plnkr" with the structure of the example, I not see any errors: http://plnkr.co/edit/nNJrobGAt5mdUzLiuGk8?p=preview

Comment: I have added ui.bootstrap in the app and yet it's giving the error.

Comment: It must be the name of the modal module, put your angular scripts

Comment: In this "plnkr" with the structure of the example, I not see any errors: http://plnkr.co/edit/nNJrobGAt5mdUzLiuGk8?p=preview

Comment: Yeah It's working in plunkr but not in my system. Can there be any reason for that?